# How to make a USB wireless adapter to support WoWLAN?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, adapter

I heard that none of the USB wireless adapters can support Wake on Wireless LAN because USB can't maintain the adapter's power when in sleep mode.  Is that true?

Is there a way to make a USB wireless adapter support WoWLAN?

Comment: So where exactly did you hear these 'rumors'?  Can you cite something that states this?  Otherwise, this is just unanswerable speculation (IMO).  When you tried to get it working, what were your results?  Where are you getting stuck while implementing it?

Comment: What you describe is device specific.  Wake on Wireless Lan must be added to the device specifications.  Likewise your ability to charge your phone while your laptop is sleeping was actually built into specifications of the laptop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The decision of whether or not to leave the USB port's power circuit enabled when the system is in ACPI S3 ("Sleep" / "Suspend to RAM") is left up to the motherboard BIOS/firmware. It *may* even have a BIOS option you can configure for this purpose, to enable/disable the USB power when the system is asleep or even turned off.

However, there aren't any motherboard implementations, *that I know of*, that will keep the **data** part of the USB connection enabled while in S3 or powered off. When the CPU is suspended or off, it doesn't make sense to maintain the data link layer of the USB bus, because even if you sent a message through the bus, the CPU wouldn't be there on the other side to receive the message. But the CPU doesn't have to be on for a normal ethernet card to do Wake on LAN, either, so I did a bit of research into this....

USB controllers are usually connected to the CPU using something like PCI or PCI Express. PCI and PCI-E support [Power Management Events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Hardware_requirements), which are essentially what is used by an on-motherboard NIC to tell the system that it's being woken up due to a WOL. In theory, if the USB controller were receiving standby power from the PCI(-E) bus, it *could* then decode a wake on LAN magic packet from a USB device, and translate that into a PCI(-E) PME, which would trigger the wake. So I believe that it is *possible*, in theory, at a hardware / system design level, to *implement* a motherboard and a USB Ethernet or WiFi chipset that would support this.

*I just don't know of any that do, off the top of my head.*

Comment: But i'd like to go into details about it. So what exactly "something like PCI or PCI Express" is? Could give a document url or something else?Actually, since usb mouse can wake the computer, i do think it's possible for a wireless adapter to do so

Comment: Yeah, but how would it happen? How would you direct a packet to a non associated wireless adapter? On wired you just broadcast the WoL for the MAC address, since it actually is connected to the ethernet switch it gets it. On wireless though, the layer2 is way different.